# How can i sort user input into a list based on conditionals

Tags: python, class, oop

So im stuck on a homework problem, and i just need some guidance or criticism if what i have so far is wrong. But the prompt is to "Create a program that will create a clothing object. The clothing object must have the following
attributes: minimum temperature, maximum temperature, and formality level. Once you have created
a list of clothes, enter the current temperature and the formality of the event that you are going to.
Then, output a list of acceptable clothes to wear based upon the formality level."

And heres what i have so far, but i dont know if i cant sort the user input into a list based on my class instances

```
class Clothing:
    def __init__(self, fit: str, mintemp: int, maxtemp: int, formalitylvl: str):
        self.fit = fit
        self.mintemp = mintemp
        self.maxtemp = maxtemp
        self.formalitylvl = formalitylvl

if __name__ == '__main__':

    listofclothes = []

    listofclothes.append(Clothing("coat", 0, 60, "yes"))
    listofclothes.append(Clothing("dress", 0, 100, "yes"))
    listofclothes.append(Clothing("T-shirt", 40, 100, "no"))
    listofclothes.append(Clothing("Hoodie", 0, 60, "no"))
    listofclothes.append(Clothing("jean shorts", 60, 100, "no"))

    catalog = int(input("please enter the number of clothing pieces you want to catalog: "))
    for i in range(catalog):
        str("please enter the clothing item: ")
        int(input("Please enter the minimmum temp you would wear the item:"))
        int(input("Please enter the maximum temp you would wear the item:"))
        str(input("Is the item formal: "))
```

Comment: You question is somewhat unclear, you wish the clothes sorted but you need to specify how you want them sorted.

Comment: sorted based on the conditions that are the attributes, for example if its cold and formal, you can wear a coat and a dress.

Comment: You should look at at Damiaan's answer it may need to be modified, however.

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track! you should save the `input` to variables and not reset the input while looping:

```
    type = input(str("please enter the clothing item: "))
    min_temp = int(input("Please enter the minimmum temp you would wear the item:"))
    max_temp = int(input("Please enter the maximum temp you would wear the item:"))
    is_formal = str(input("Is the item formal: "))
```

Now, `loop` over the clothes and check which are right:

```
output_list = []
for item in listofclothes:
    if (item.fit == type and item.mintemp == min_temp and item.maxtemp == max_temp and item.formalitylvl == is_formal):
        output_list.append(item)
```

I've removed your `catalog` range since it is not mentioned in your assignment. Furthermore, it is not what you should loop over. You should loop over the `list` of clothes!

EDIT: added `type` for `fit` since I forgot that clothing part.